# Msg to Eml converting by RDOmessage.saveas shows broken text for Korean

Tags: outlook-redemption

Thanks for sharing us this great tool!

I tested converting msg files to eml files using AutoIt, Outlook2016, and redemption.dll Version 5.24 as follows.

```
#include <OutlookEX.au3>
$Application = _OL_Open()  ; just for check
$Session = ObjCreate("Redemption.RDOSession")
$Session.MAPIOBJECT = $Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT   ; just for check
$Msg = $Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("d:\test\EML 변환 TEST.msg")   
$Msg.Display   ; just for check
$Msg.SaveAs("d:\test\Test1.eml",1024)
```

There is no problem with reading or showing the msg file in Outlook with redemption.dll in terms of Korean.
However, when converting eml files with SaveAs, all Korean characters are broken.

The original msg file in this test, the file converted to eml using redemption.dll, and the file converted to eml using other tools are compressed and [linked](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CKgtlNqewj0BLAi2rmxPVtxwKOx9IPfa/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks.

Comment: Please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com for an updated version.

Comment: Thanks for a feedback. I sent an email.

Comment: I sent you a link to the updated version. Let me know how / if it works for you.